# is out there any Open Source phpmyadmin flash user intrface?

Tags: apache-flex, flash, actionscript-3, mxml, phpmyadmin

is out there any Open Source phpmyadmin flash user intrface?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Not quite what you asked for, but have you looked at [FlashMyAdmin](http://osflash.org/flashmyadmin)?